# Send redirect to relative path in JSP?

Tags: jsp, redirect, send, relative-path

```
response.sendRedirect("../seja/izpisknjig.jsp");
```

the file in which I execute this line is index.jsp. the directory structure looks like this.
project
--index.jsp
seja
--izpisknjig.jsp

How do I form the relative path to redirect to izpisknjig.jsp.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Most reliable would be to create a domain-relative URL with the context path included.

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/seja/izpisknjig.jsp");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JSP taglib** to do redirection.

Content of index.jsp file :

```
<jsp:forward page="../seja/izpisknjig.jsp" />
```

If project and seja are at root of your webapp context ( ie. http://host:port/context/project )

Content of index.jsp file :

```
<jsp:forward page="/seja/izpisknjig.jsp" />
```

Answer (score -2):

You may be overthinking this.  You could just pier some generate some javascript to redirect anywhere you like.

```
  document.location = "MyPage.php?action=DoThis";
```

Comment: How can this work if your a redirecting in the servlet?

Comment: You would do something similar to the 301 or 302 redirect listed [here](http://www.301-redirect.info/en/301-redirect-with-jsp.html).

Comment: The question is about a server redirection, not a client redirection coded in Javascript.