# How to redirect from inside a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, redirect

I have a JSP page and need to introduce *conditional* redirect logic. For instance, if a variable is above a certain threshold, then continue rendering the JSP like normal. Otherwise, I need to redirect the browser to, say, `http://myapp.example.com/fizz`.

```
if(var > threshold) {
    // Render page like normal
} else {
    // Redirect to http://myapp.example.com/fizz.
}
```

Any ideas as to how I could accomplish the redirect portion of this (from inside a JSP page)?

Comment: `response.sendRedirect(http://myapp.example.com/fizz)` i think you want this

Comment: Thanks @JqueryLearner (+1) - should the URL be inside quotes though? And a semi-colon at the end?

Comment: please don't use scriplets inside jsp as you are doing with the above as its a bad practice. use custom tag libraries instead. as for your problem i guess senredirect will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

@IAmYourFaja
If you want skip scriplet for better practice of code, then try like this by JSTL tag.

```
<c:if test="${var gt threshold}">
       <c:redirect url="http://myapp.example.com/fizz"/> // Redirect to http://myapp.example.com/fizz.
</c:if>
```

Don't need to add any other things. hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 reponse.sendRedirect("http://myapp.example.com/fizz");
```

Just add this

Comment: Thanks @gau123 (+1) - don't I need a semi-colon at the end though? And would my redirect simply be: `response.sendRedirect("http://myapp.example.com/fizz");`?

Comment: Yes u hav to put a semicolon at the end..and redirect be like    response.sendRedirect("http://myapp.example.com/fizz");

Comment: Thanks again @gau123 (+1) - just curious as to how this works though...if I don't specify "http://", then what if I want to use SSL (https)?

Comment: reponse -> response

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
<%
// New location to be redirected
String site = new String("http://myapp.example.com/fizz");
response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
response.setHeader("Location", site); 
%>
```

or you can also use-

```
<%    
  response.sendRedirect("http://myapp.example.com/fizz");
 %>
```

You can use any approach from both of them.

Answer (score 0):

inside your else loop you can use

```
response.sendRedirect("http://myapp.example.com/fizz");
```

yes the Url should be within double quotes(`""`) because

[response.sendRedirect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) accepts a String argument

and yes a `;` should be at the end otherwise your code wont compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String site = new String("http://www.google.com");
  response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
  response.setHeader("Location", site);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your query in the gau123 answer to your question

```
if I don't specify "http://", then what if I want to use SSL (https)?
```

For that you could use ur project path,for example if you want to go to the link **`http://myapp.example.com/fizz`** or even with **`https://myapp.example.com/fizz`**

you will use `reponse.sendRedirect("../fizz");`

In both cases it will redirect you to the fizz page

Also Most reliable would be to create a domain-relative URL with the context path included.

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/fizz");
```

(Referred from [Send redirect to relative path in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940329/send-redirect-to-relative-path-in-jsp))