# How to remove index.jsp from being displayed in URL?

Tags: jsp, url

I have a JSP website and don't want it to be displayed as http://www.mywebsite.com/index.jsp. Is there any way to omit the index.jsp from being displayed? I want just my website name as homepage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect from inside a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952848/how-to-redirect-from-inside-a-jsp)

Answer (score 1):

If you define `index.jsp` as a *welcome-file* you can omit it in the URL, however the URL that explictly references the JSP will still work.

To define that page as a welcome-file add the following block to your `web.xml`:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```