# How to call a jsp file from servlet using relative url

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am a beginner and need some help.
I am having specific requirement where i need to pass a url. That URL should call a jsp where i can process my result and redirect to different servlet.

i have mapped the jsp in web.xml under servlet-mapping tag.
and in my servlet i am trying to call jsp using relative url something like below.

I have mentioned in doGet() what exactly i want but not able to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
```

```
<servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/jsp/index.jsp</url-pattern>
```

```
protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
throws ServletException, IOException
{
 String url = "/jsp/index.jsp";

// now my requirement is to invoke this url from anywhere inside my      program or any other servlet.
}
```

My requirement is to be able to call mentioned url in my program or any other servlet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How about putting that url in `session` and used it anywhere in your program ?

Comment: Thanks Swati.. but that url it self not getting up. That is the problem.

Comment: You can use [getContextPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940329/send-redirect-to-relative-path-in-jsp) how to do it